# faster way of sparse to array multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matmul

I m trying to multiply 300000 x 300000 sparse matrix with a single array of 300000, and its taking 7-8 seconds by matmul numpy.

NumPy matmul is what I have used. Is there any other option?

Comment: You aren't using `np.matmul`, are you?  `M@arr` uses `Ms` own version of matrix multiplication.

Comment: yes i m using A@B

Comment: Is np.matmul and @ are two different operations

Comment: `A@B` is translated to `A.__matmul__(B)`.  `np.matmul(A,B)` first makes sure all arguments are `numpy.ndarray`, which is not what you want for a sparse matrix.  Anyways, the sparse matrix multiplication is pretty well developed, so I wouldn't expect to find a faster alternative.  If `A` is already `ndarray`, `A@B` may be faster, but that's not an option with your sizes.

Comment: Yes, actually A matrix is a sparse matrix with float32 values, and u is an array

Comment: Details are missing to *make this reproducible*. For example, what kind of sparse matrix do you use (eg. CSR, DOK, etc), what datatype, what is the ratio of non-zeros values in the sparce matrix, what processor, do you have enough RAM, etc. Results can be very different regarding theses things. Thus, please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I m using CSR sparse matrix, using M1 processor 16GB ram.

Comment: and ratio of non zero value is about 1% only.

Comment: This matrix is already quite big. It should take 6.7 GiB. Thus, the time is not so surprising to me. That being said, I expected this to be faster. I spent a lot of time trying to generate a random matrix like this without filling my whole memory (also 16 GiB). In the end, it takes a bit more than 8 GiB on my machine and 1.3 second for the matrix multiplication. This is not optimal but reasonable. The first time, my RAM was saturated and it took 4-6 seconds. Since the M1 should be a bit faster than my CPU for that and you do not have more RAM, I think you run out of memory and use the swap.